# Why are lifecycle methods in activity class defined with protected access specifier

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

### Why are the lifeCycle methods in android have access specifiers as `protected` ?

---

***what i understand about Access-specifiers is as below***::

[image]

---

- But why should we need to make all the life-cycle methods as
  protected
- I notice this when i override the lifecycle methods
- I know over-riding the methods of Activity class as methods in
  `Activity class` are defined `protected`
- But why are they defined as `protected`

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- They are [`protected`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/215505/1175253) for encapsulation within the framework package [android.app](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/package-summary.html) and subclasses.
- They are to be called by [`android.app.ActivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) (same package) only. Depending on the method implementation, things could get messed up, if one can call those methods arbitrarily, from anywhere.

So, this is by design and that design helps to avoid certain conceptual errors.
If you really must have a `public` method, just implement one and use it from outside and within the corresponding lifecycle method.
However, though not recommended in this case, one could override `protected` methods with `public` methods.

Answer (score 1):

i am defining here why public and protected and how it work:

It's useful to have `public onClick` methods because you can "force" certain buttons to be clicked programmatically. A common example of this is causing the same to code to execute when the user presses the enter key, or pressed the Submit button.

I don't think Android calls Activity.`onCreate` directly. Note that Activity inherits from `Context (which does have a public constructor).` It is my understanding that the constructor triggers some events to occur, and the `onCreate/Pause/Resume/Destroy` methods are called internally to the class at the appropriate time.

For example, when you create an activity, the view XML file has to be parsed and inflated. This happens automatically, so there's something happening behind the scenes that you don't directly control.

Answer (score 1):

Not public because those lifecycle methods are essentially used internally by the SDK and are not meant to be called by any other classes (you are not supposed to call anywhere `activity.onResume()` from any class, this is done automatically).

Not private to allow some custom code to be ran by subclasses.